# parse this directory path without losing slash

Tags: python, string, wxpython, escaping

I have a wxPython application. I am taking in a directory path from a textbox using GetValue().

I notice that while trying to write this string to a variable:

`"C:\Documents and Settings\tchan\Desktop\InputFile.xls"`,

python sees the string as

`'C:\\Documents and Settings\tchan\\Desktop\\InputFile.xls'` (missing a slash between "Settings" and "UserName).

More info:

The directory path string is created by the "open file" dialog, which creates a standard 'choose file' dialog you see in any 'open' function in a text processor. The string is written to a textbox and read later when the main thread begins (in case the user wants to change it).

**EDIT**: I realise that the problem comes from the '\t' being seen as a "tab" instead of normal forward slash. However I don't know how to work past this, since

Comment: Wait, you're saying that the wx control is giving you that broken string?

Comment: i'm using the wxPython module to create a GUI. I have an "open file" button that I use to select the file on my desktop, which returns the string mentioned above. ("C:\Documents and Settings\tchan\Desktop\InputFile.xls"). This string is passed to the textBox on the application GUI, and I also read it into a variable to use later to save my file.

Comment: Could you post the code you use and indicate the earliest point at which the string is wrong?

Comment: basically you if do a x = 'C:\Documents and Settings\tchan\Desktop\InputFile.xls'  then print x you'll know what i mean

Comment: Are you using eval or something?  The behavior you are seeing happens when the Python interpreter tries to evaluate a string literal, not when it performs an operation on an existing string variable.  It can also be suppressed by adding an r:


x=r'C:\Documents and Settings\tchan\Desktop\InputFile.xls'

Comment: the textBox GUI is 'reading' the text inside the textBox, which I assume is similar to an  x = "string" assignment in the interpreter. The program can't see the actual string until after it has been assigned to a variable (since it assigns the textbox value using GetValue()), so x = r'string' wouldn't work. But anyway, James Snyder has the solution with '%r' %variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect there's a different way to get that path from wx that would avoid this issue, since it seems like this would be a fairly common problem.  That said, there are a few ways to fix a mangled path like you describe, by converting the string you have to a raw string.

```
rawpath = "%r" % path
```

The resulting rawpath will likely be somewhat messy since it will probably add extra escapes to the backslashes and give you something like:

```
"'C:\\\\Documents and Settings\\tchan\\\\Desktop\\\\InputFile.xls'"
```

It seems like os.path.normpath will clean that up though.

```
import os.path
os.path.normpath(rawpath)
```

Comment: perfect, thats the raw type conversion i didn't know about (no such thing as a raw_string()). And normpath is smart enough to reduce 2 slashes here and no slashes there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

not saying this is the correct solution, but you can

```
x = "C:\tmp".encode('string-escape')
x
'C:\\tmp'
```

better, if you are using the file dialog

```
os.path.join(dlg.GetDirectory(),dlg.GetFilename())
```

where dlg is your dialog

Comment: in this case , not much, it adds double escapes much like @James' answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the slashes. `\\` will store a literal `\` in the string:

```
path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\tchan\\Desktop\\InputFile.xls"
```